# Using a webform checksum for multiple contacts

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, checksum

I have set up a webform for users to create memberships. There needs to be 3 contacts within the webform: organisation (where the membership sits), main contact, representative.

I would like to email renewal notices with a checksum so the user can quickly update and renew membership. This somewhat works. The organisation information is displayed in the checksum link. However the main contact and representative is not. I can see why this does not work.

I can think of 2 ways round this:

1. Create custom fields for an organisation contacting main contact and representative information.
2. Create a login so users can update their contact information.

At the moment I am thinking the first option would be better suited. Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: in the mailing that goes out can you use the Fuzion Extended Token extension so you can put the cid of the related folk in to the url?

Comment: Thanks for your message. That looks like a handy extension. I haven't had any success getting it to work with relationship tokens, they come back empty when emailed. The tokens for the membership information work fine (such as end date). Do you have any idea when this is? I'm assuming this would be the token needed: Relationship: Representative is : ID of first contact found.